# Discord Bot (node.js) : read data from external file

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I set up my discord BOT using node.js. For my advantage, I would need to store some data on a external file, but I don't seem to be able to access it from my index.js file (the main Bot file). 
I've tried having one static array in the external js/json files, but I can only retrieve undefined/empty values. Additionally, when I tried with a .txt file, once retrieved the content, I found it unable to call functions such as `string.split()`.

Did I miss something in the package content perhaps?

Comment: We can't help you unless you show us the code you tried.

Comment: If you want to look at using a separate file, [JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON) might be able to help you there. It's a bit hard to know what you're trying to do, so edit your question and add some code.

Comment: I only need to basically store a list of predefined replies of the BOT, so I tried again with a simple .txt file and splitting the lines, and it works. Now I look like dumb but I swear yesterday my console was throwing me weird errors such as `TypeError: text.split() is not a function`...

Comment: Probably because it wasn't a string. `.split();` can return an error like that if the thing you're trying to do it to isn't a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the data you are storing is in UTF-8 encoding:

```
var fs = require('fs');

fs.readFile('path/to/file', 'utf8', function(err, contents) {
    // code using file data
});
```

Assuming no errors contents will be a string of the data that is inside that file.

https://code-maven.com/reading-a-file-with-nodejs

Comment: I was about to post the part of my code, but this snippet works like a charm with a .txt file, splitting the lines. Thanks very much!